# UiTableView inside another Table

Tags: xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have a list of DataBase's records. In my screen I need a Table on the top of my page to show all these records then, when user tap one of this records, the table on bottom of my screen displays details about this record. So my first table, on top, has to be dynamic and my second table, on botton, could be even static.

My idea was to set UITableViewController to static then, in first table's section place one big row which contains a table:
 - Before I tried placing a Table View directly inside this row,
 - then I placed a container which contains an UITableViewController.

In both cases is a mess! I can't understand how to manage UITableViewDataSource for both tables and data's flow between them!

What's the best way to do something like that? Are there some tutorials??

Comment: I think its not a very good design approach to place a table view within a table view, or for that matter scrolling within scrolling. You should reconsider your design. I could be wrong though, just my opinion. I would split the screen (UIViewController) into two halves and have two table views, one for above and one for below. And then in your delegate methods check which table view is responding to the delegate and then do your work. Selection in the above table defines the data source for the table below.

Comment: Ye, probably is better... However (just a curiosity) if I place two tables in the same ViewController, is there a way to manage their two different DataSource?

Comment: As I mentioned, yes it should be possible. Set the delegate for both of them as self. Then in the delegate methods check which table view is responding using a if condition. More like if(tableView == self.table1)